# Copy sheets from different workbooks into a single workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy the first sheet from multiple workbooks into a new workbook, on separate sheets, and summarise the data in one more sheet at the end of the workbook.

At the moment my workbook creation isn't really working. It copies the first sheet into a new workbook but then stops working:

> error 9, subscript out of range

```
Sub MergeSelectedWorkbooks()
    Dim SummaryBook As Workbook
    Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
    Dim NRow As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim WorkBk As Workbook
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Set SummaryBook = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    FolderPath = "Path here"
    ChDrive FolderPath
    ChDir FolderPath
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
       filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)
    Nrow = 1
    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        Set SummarySheet = Workbook.Worksheets(NRow) 'this is what seems to be the reason it doesn't work

        Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FileName)
        Application.Run WorkBk.Name & "!Macro" 'this runs a macro in the workbook that I want to copy the sheet from
        Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:G21")
        Set DestRange = SummarySheet.Range("A1:G21")
        Set DestRange = DestRange.Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, _
           SourceRange.Columns.Count)

        DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value
        NRow = NRow + 1
        WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False
    Next NFile

    SummarySheet.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Workbook creation? Isn't "really" working?  Please be specific.

Comment: Please try to explain **exactly** what your code actually does and what you expect instead. Explain where you got any errors and which, or where you got stuck. Also include in your explanation what `Application.Run WorkBk.Name & "!Macro"` is doing. Best is to [edit] your original question to improve the mentioned points.

Comment: I've edited the initial question, I hope this clears things up !

Comment: In which line does the error occur?

Comment: Set SummarySheet = Workbook.Worksheets(NRow)

Comment: `Workbook` is a reserved word and should not be used as a variable name! But probably this is a typo and you meant `WorkBk` instead? Consider using `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (google for this if you need a howto) and it will prevent you from mis-typed variable names.

Comment: I replaced it with "SummaryBook" but it still gives me the same error. It looks like at the moment it is copying the sheets in separate workbooks instead of separate sheets in the same workbook until it stops working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160798/discussion-between-peh-and-doule).

Comment: I don't really know why but "creating" all the sheets outside the loop rather than adding a new sheet with each loop seems to have solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm